# Trouble converting Json Array into Pojo with array of pojos

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

JSON String

```
{
"order":{
  "address":{
     "city":"seattle"
  },
  "orderItem":[
     {
        "itemId":"lkasj",
        "count":2
     },
     {
        "itemId":"ldka",
        "count":3
     }
  ]
   }
}
```

Order Class

```
public class Order {
private OrderItem[] orderItems;
private CustomerAddress address;

Order(OrderItem[] orderItems, CustomerAddress address ) {
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
    this.address = address;

}

public OrderItem[] getOrderItems() {
    return orderItems;
}

public void setOrderItems(OrderItem[] orderItems) {
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
}

public CustomerAddress getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(CustomerAddress address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

My OrderItem class
    package com.cbd.backend.model;

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class OrderItem {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String itemId;
    private String count;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

unit Test that blows up

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Unit test to demonstrate issue
    package com.cbd.backend.model;

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class OrderTest {

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  @Test
    public void gsonToOrder() {
        Order order = gson.fromJson( a, Order.class );
        assertNotNull(order);
        assertNotNull(order.getOrderItems()[0]);
    }
    private final String a = "{ \"order\": { \"address\": { \"city\": \"seattle\" },\"orderItem\":[{ \"itemId\":\"lkasj\", \"count\":2 }, { \"itemId\":\"ldka\", \"count\":3 } ] } }";
}
```

Should I be using something other than gson or am i constructing this incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. The root element of your JSON is "order", but the class does not have a property with this name. Try changing you model or just removing the element from the JSON.
2. There is a mismatch in the name of the "orderItem" property. It is plural in the class, but singular in the JSON.

To sum it up, the following JSON will work without any changes to the code.

```json
{
    "address":{
        "city":"seattle"
    },
    "orderItems":[
        {
            "itemId":"lkasj",
            "count":2
        },
        {
            "itemId":"ldka",
            "count":3
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, "count" as it appears in the JSON seems to be numeric, so you might want to change the type of `OrderItem.count` to `int` or `java.lang.Integer`.